# Shortening URL params with MVC routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a url along the lines of this:

> example.com/profile/publicview?profileKey=5

and I want to shorten it to this with routing

> example.com/profile/5

How do I do this?

This is my attempt:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Profile", "Profile/{profileKey}", 
    new { controller = "Profile", action = "PublicView", profileKey ="" }
);
```

But his produces this error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a
>   null entry for parameter 'profileKey'
>   of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'
>   for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   PublicView(Int32)' in
>   'Website.Controllers.ProfileController

Action method

```
public ActionResult PublicView(int profileKey)
  {
        //stuff
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the code to your PublicView() action method where the exception is being thrown?

Comment: Done. Didn't include the method body as its not getting that far.

Comment: Try the answers given by Mike and I at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the controller change the PublicView(int? profileKey)

**ANSWER TO COMMENT**

Yes, but since your default value in the route is null, you need to handle it.  Otherwise, change the default in your route.

**MAYBE**

This probably won't help, but it is worth a try.  Here is the code I have my site:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "freebies",                                              // Route name
            "freebies/{page}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Freebies", page = 1 }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

And the link:

```
http://localhost/freebies/2
```

And this works fine.

Comment: It would allow the route to work correctly. Then all you would need to do is, inside the action do profileKey.HasValue. If it is, then you have an int. Otherwise, you can either redirect elsewhere, or throw an error.

Comment: This answer tell mes how to stop the exception which is the wrong approche. The exception shouldnt happen in the first place if the routing is done right.

Answer (score 1):

Your route and action method are fine as-is, if and only if, you are always including an integer value in your url as in *example.com/profile/**5***. (I assume this route is defined above the Default route)

What you've defined is a route that defaults profileKey to an empty string if it is not provided in the url, and within your action method you've attempted to bind this value to a non-nullable integer, so if you are attempting *example.com/profile* or *example.com/profile/not-an-int* this will throw the exception you are reporting. Your route will assign an empty string to profileKey, but your action method fails to cast this as an integer. As Martin [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281933/shortening-url-params-with-mvc-routing/1281975#1281975), one way around this is to use a nullable int instead. An alternative solution would be to default this value in your route to an integer.

If you are still getting the error, make sure the actual URL you are requesting is correct and has the profileKey included. I know sometimes when using the default html and/or url helpers I make a mistake passing in the routeValues and end up rendering a link or posting to a url other than what I was expecting...

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Is that your only route?  If not, maybe another route (declared earlier) is matching first, and isn't picking up the profileKey parameter properly.

Comment: I read it could be this, so iv commented out all the other routes, so I only have this one, and then the default. But it didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested) code

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Profile", "Profile/{profileKey}", 
    new { controller = "Profile", action = "PublicView" }
);
```

Comment: No that cause the same exception.  The best I can come up with is  routes.MapRoute("Profile", "Profile", new { controller = "Profile", action = "PublicView" }); but this produces a url of example.com/profile?profileKey=5, which still isnt perfect.

Comment: I tested it should work. Would you post your method signature?